# R- Coercing different date formats into one

Tags: r, date

I imported a messy spreadsheet that I  want to process in R. There is a date field that may appear in three ways (in any order in any position):

- text as `ddt <- "2018-01-01"`;
- number as `ddn <- 43101`;
- text as `dde <- "43102"`

The following function will autodetect the and convert these three formats into the desired "%YY-%m-%d":

```
coerce.Date <- function (date, origin = "1900-01-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d"){
  out <- ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(date)),date,as.numeric(date))
  as.Date(out,origin = origin, format = format)
}
```

Thus:

```
dd <- c(ddt,ddn,dde)

dates <- lapply(dd,coerce.Date)

str(dates)

List of 3
 $ : Date[1:1], format: "2018-01-01"
 $ : Date[1:1], format: "2018-01-04"
 $ : Date[1:1], format: "2018-01-03"
```

Great. However when getting back to a vector it gives me:

```
unlist(dates)

[1] 17532 17535 17534
```

The workaround I got is:

```
dates <- tibble(dates)

unnest (dates)

# A tibble: 3 x 1
  dates        
  <date>   
1 2018-01-01
2 2018-01-04
3 2018-01-03
```

Is there an easier way?

PS: I also tried `sapply`, but it turned out to be more confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the class again, this also avoids the warning:

```
ddt <- "2018-01-01"
ddn <- 43101
dde <- "43102"

dd <- c(ddt,ddn,dde)

coerce.Date <- function (dateVar, origin = "1900-01-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d"){
  if(!identical(grep("^[[:digit:]]*$", dateVar), integer(0))){
    out <- as.Date(as.numeric(dateVar),origin = origin, format = format)
  } else {
    out <- as.Date(dateVar, origin = origin, format = format)
  }
  return(out)
}

myDates <- lapply(dd, coerce.Date)

class(myDates) <- "Date"

myDates
```